# Rational dependences between algebraic numbers not closed under Galois conjugation

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $d > m > 1$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m$ be a (strict) subset of all the distinct roots of $p$. Can the value of $c_1\alpha_1 + \ldots + c_m\alpha_m$, where $c_1, \ldots, c_m$ are non-zero rationals, be rational? I would appreciate any suggestions.

I imagine the answer is negative, and it can be somehow proven by taking the splitting field of $p$ and applying the automorphisms to the sum above.

Comment: This is not about multiplicity: of course $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m$ all are roots of $p$ with multiplicity one. It is about (for example) whether there exist rational $c_1, c_2$ such that $c_1\omega + c_2\omega^2$ is rational, where $\omega$ is the fourth root of three.

Comment: It is "a set of distinct roots", not "the set of all distinct roots of $p$"

Comment: Just changed it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Let $p(x) = x^4-2$, which is irreducible of degree $4$ (irreducibility follows from Eistenstein's Criterion at $p=2$).

The sum of the two real roots, $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $-\sqrt[4]{2}$, is $0$; so is the sum of the two nonreal roots, $i\sqrt[4]{2}$, and $-i\sqrt[4]{2}$. So we can take $m=2$, $\alpha_1\in\{\sqrt[4]{2},i\sqrt[4]{2}\}$, and $\alpha_2=-\alpha_1$, $c_1=c_2=1$. The sum is $0$, which of course is rational.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow got blinded by wishful thinking that it is not possible, will check more thoroughly before the next question.